# Does Java have support for multicore processors/parallel processing?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, multicore

I know that now that most processors have two or more cores, multicore programming is all the rage. Is there functionality to utilize this in Java? I know that Java has a Thread class, but I also know this was around a long time before multicores became popular. If I can make use of multiple cores in Java, what class/technique would I use?

Comment: I asked a very similar question awhile back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532826/java-multi-threading-beginner-questions

I suggest you read through the answers to that one.

Comment: @Carl: I asked more about *new* functionality rather than old uses of threads. I specifically want to know about new classes (notice no one answers your question with java.util.Concurrent)

Comment: Let me rephrase: you would use the class Thread/Callable (because as all of the answers to my question point out, Thread/Callable "just works" on multicore machines).  Using Thread/Callable usually implies also using java.util.concurrent - but that has nothing to do with single vs multicore implementation.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Does Java have support for multicore
>   processors/parallel processing?

Yes. It also has been a platform for other programming languages where the implementation added a "true multithreading" or "real threading" selling point. The [G1 Garbage Collector](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/g1_intro.jsp) introduced in newer releases also makes use of multi-core hardware.

### Java Concurrency in Practice

Try to get a copy of the *[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/)* book.

---

> If I can make use of multiple cores in
>   Java, what class/technique would I
>   use?

### `java.util.concurrent`

> **Utility classes** commonly useful in
>   **concurrent programming**. This package
>   includes a few small standardized
>   extensible frameworks, as well as some
>   classes that provide useful
>   functionality and are otherwise
>   tedious or difficult to implement.
>   Here are brief descriptions of the
>   main components.

**Executors**

`Executor` is a simple standardized interface for defining custom thread-like subsystems, including thread pools, asynchronous IO, and lightweight task frameworks.

**Queues**

The java.util.concurrent `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` class supplies an efficient scalable thread-safe non-blocking FIFO queue.

**Timing**

The `TimeUnit` class provides multiple granularities (including nanoseconds) for specifying and controlling time-out based operations. Most classes in the package contain operations based on time-outs in addition to indefinite waits.

**Synchronizers**

Four classes aid common special-purpose synchronization idioms. `Semaphore` is a classic concurrency tool. `CountDownLatch` is a very simple yet very common utility for blocking until a given number of signals, events, or conditions hold. [...]

**Concurrent Collections**

Besides Queues, this package supplies a few Collection implementations designed for use in multithreaded contexts: `ConcurrentHashMap`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, and `CopyOnWriteArraySet`.

---

This also comes in handy if you want to match the number of threads to the number of available CPUs for example:

```
int n = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Answer (score 9):

In most Java implementations, you can rely on Java threads being real OS threads.  As a result, the operating system will take care of making sure that the workload is distributed across multiple cores if you use the Thread class.

Operating system threads pre-date commodity multicore systems by a long time, so that's not a concern really.  The only difference multicore systems made was to allow time-multiplexed operating system threads to be executed as truly concurrent threads on multiple cores.

Answer (score 8):

Java 5 introduced the java.util.concurrent package which helps in building concurrent applications that can benefit from multicore systems. This package goes way beyond the  multithreading functionality offered in Java 1.4 and earlier (like synchronized, wait, notify, etc).

There's a proposal for Java 7 to include the [Fork/Join](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/fork_join) framework to make use of multicore systems easier.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find ***new*** functionality in Ateji PX, an extension of the Java language with parallel primitives inspired from pi-calculus. Quite different from thread programming and everything thread-based (Tasks, Executors, etc).

Parallelism introduced this way at the language level, as opposed to threading librairies that provide API access to a mostly hardware-level concept, makes multicore programming much simpler and intuitive.

It's a radically new approach to parallel programming worth reading about (disclaimer: I am the designer of Ateji PX). The whitepaper is here : http://www.ateji.com/px/whitepapers/Ateji%20PX%20for%20Java%20v1.0.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Java provides [concurrent API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) to avail advantages of multi-core processors of machine.

You can get available processors count from Runtime and use that count to create [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) through many APIs in [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

You can also use [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) API to achieve the same.

Java 8 provides one more API : newWorkStealingPool, which create ForkJoinPool by using all available processors. You don't have to pass processor count as parameter.

Have a look at sample to code:

```
int processorCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processorCount);
ExecutorService executor2 =  
                            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(processorCount);
ExecutorService executor3 = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(); // java-8 API
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(processorCount);
```

Have a look at related SE question right Executor:

[Java's Fork/Join vs ExecutorService - when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156599/javas-fork-join-vs-executorservice-when-to-use-which/34922218#34922218)