# Java multiprocessing

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have certain requirement where I need to process large data with some mysql operation, there are multiple run of the similar kind. A single run takes around 2 hrs.

If I run each run in separate java thread there was no major time saving. As per my understanding java threads are not multi process ie its only a way to obtain parallelism not to improve CPU utilization.

If there is any way I can make use of multiple processor on the same machine through java, I guess that could save some time for all run operations.

Please let me know if the problem is clear here and have any idea on the solution.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223072/how-do-i-optimize-for-multi-core-and-multi-cpu-computers-in-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330430/does-java-have-support-for-multicore-processors-parallel-processing

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is actually an SQL question.

Comment: How do you know your computation is not constrained by access to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in your application or in mysql.
Java does support multi-threading and your application should benefit automatically from multiple cores.
Probably there is a common resource that needs to be synchronized.

From what you say, "process large data", i bet the common resource is the database file and memory.

If a single run takes a minute or more (in your case: 120 minutes), than you're better off with multiple *processes* anyway, as the overhead of the JVM startup is neglectible.