# Stanford LexParser Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, nlp, stanford-nlp

I was using Stanford Lexparser recently. Unfortunately, I have encountered a problem as it take a very long time especially when I pass in a large file. Will multithreading help improve the performance? I know that multithreading can be easily done in command line. However, I would like to multithread it using the API internally. Currently, I am using this code. How I make it multithread?

```
for (List<HasWord> sentence : new DocumentPreprocessor(fileReader)) {
        parse = lp.apply(sentence);
        TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("typedDependenciesCollapsed");
        tp.printTree(parse, pw);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to multithread it?  [here is a post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3330440/3960399) that goes into some detail about different approaches

Comment: does printTree literally prints something? If so, then most time is spent by printer anyway, and multithreading won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use regular old Java thread to annotate documents in parallel. For example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,parse");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation ann = new Annotation("your sentence here");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  new Thread() {
    @Override public void run() {
      pipeline.annotate(ann);  // except, you should probably annotate different documents.
      Tree tree = ann.get(SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0).get(TreeAnnotation.class);
    }
  }.start();
}
```

Another option is to use the [simple API](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  new Thread() {
    @Override public void run() {
      Tree tree = new Sentence("your sentence").parse();
    }
  }.start();
}
```

At a high level though, you're unlikely to get a phenomenally huge speedup from multithreading. Parsing is generally slow (O(n^3) wrt the sentence length) and multithreading only gives you max linear speedup in the number of cores. An alternative for making things faster would to be to either use [the shift reduce parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml), or, if you're ok with dependency and not constituency parses, the [Stanford Neural Dependency Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml).